# Is there way to hook vue component ready (initialize)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

see my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/roroco/ohua4uag/), I hope hook component ready with following code:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
  <ro-tag></ro-tag>
</div>
<script>
  Vue.component("ro-tag", {
    ready: function () {
      console.log("ready")
    },
    template: "<div></div>"
  })
  new Vue({el: "#app"})
</script>
</body>
```

the ready function isn't invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready` has been [replaced](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced) with mounted hook in vue 2.x.x. you can use [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook which gets:

> Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el

see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohua4uag/1/).